# Implementation of Stateful LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I want to create a stateful LSTM

My data is of 68871 x 43, where the features are in the column no. 1-42 and label in column no. 43

My keras LSTM code for classification of the data is

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dropout
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
# convert an array of values into a dataset matrix
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back):
    dataX, dataY= [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0:43]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 43])
    return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)
# fix random seed for reproducibility
#numpy.random.seed(7)
# load the dataset
look_back=5
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("Source.txt", delimiter=" ")
# normalize the dataset
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset[:,0:43] = scaler.fit_transform(dataset[:,0:43])
# split into train and test sets
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)
print trainX.shape
#trainX=numpy.reshape(trainX,(46117,43,25))
# create and fit the LSTM network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, input_dim=43))
#model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adagrad')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, nb_epoch=10, batch_size=5)
model.evaluate(testX, testY, batch_size=1)
```

Please suggest what changes to be made in order to make the LSTM stateful
Thanks so much in advance !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(5,43), stateful=True))
```

is what you are looking for I think. See [here for documentation](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#recurrent).

Also, if you want to use stateful lstm it doesn't make sense to shuffle the training data (which is the default). Therefore modify this line too:

```
model.fit(trainX, trainY, nb_epoch=10, batch_size=5, shuffle=False)
```

Comment: The input shape must be provided in model.add() , I have tried with many input sizes but it is throwing errors.

Can you please suggest some valid input size ?

Comment: what does print trainX.shape give ?

Comment: it prints (46137, 5, 43)

:  46137 is the no. of train samples
5 is the lstm timestep
43 is the number of input dimensions

Comment: edited my answer. You are feeding sequences of length 5 where each timestamp is a 1D tensor of length 43 if I understand correctly. So the input of your lstm is of shape (5,43).

Comment: did that answer your question?

Comment: It didn't answer correctly. After I fixed the batch_input_shape to (32, 100, 43) then it started working correctly.

Comment: Then you changed your batch size in the fit() function. And you never mentionned that the timesteps were 100. If hour trainX.shape prints (46137,5,43) then it should have worked. You are describing me training data that has the shape (N,100,43) and batch_size=32. This is not the information written in the question above.

Comment: You could equivalently write input_shape=(100,43) so that you are not relying on a hardcoded batch_size.